# Резиновое изменений пропорций элементов сайта

Tags: html, css

Правильная ли задумка пропорцианально изменять размеры элементов сайта относительно высоты/ширины экрана?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос относительный. Задавай размеры в процентах, наблюдай как будет на мобильных смотреться. Если не устроит то задавай размеры по медиа-запросам. Всё по пожеланиям заказчика

Comment: Согласен, для адаптивной верстки лучше всего использовать относительные значения `%`, `em`, `rem`, `vh`, `vw`